# How do you prove that something is a function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have a problem like this: $$x = y^9 + 2y^7 + 3y^5 - 5y^3 + 15y + 1$$ and I have to show that for $Γ ⊂ ℝ × ℝ$ and $(x, y) ∈ Γ$ would be a functional relation (if I translated that from my language correctly). I know that to prove something is a function there has to be only one $x$ for the $f(x)$ and I can prove it on functions that are more plottable and predictive but for something like this that I can't plot without help of the computer and that has unpredictive behavior I just don't have any idea how to do problems like this. Is there some trick of solving this or maybe something I can read on this topic of proving whether something is a function?

Comment: If the map is increasing (and if you can prove that it is increasing), then it will be invertible.

Comment: And if it is invertible it is a function?

Comment: If $x$ is an invertible function of $y$, then you can invert it (in principle) to get $y$ as a function of $x$.

Comment: Got it. And how do you prove that something like this has an increasing map?

Comment: If the derivative is positive, the map is increasing (but surely you know that?).

Comment: :)). Thank you for help